# Is SAML certificate redundant?

Tags: certificate, salesforce, saml

To configure Salesforce for SAML SSO you need to upload your organization's SAML certificate (step 7 [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_saml.htm&language=en)).

At the same time, I can see that SAML certificate is part of organization IdP metadata file:

```
<IDPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>...
                </X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </KeyDescriptor>
    ...
</IDPSSODescriptor>
```

Doesn't that make SAML certificate upload redundant?

Answer (score 1):

For SAML the certitifiate does not need to be send in any other form than metadata. Salesforce may need this for other puruposes though. The implementation may require the certificate to be installed. This is the case in OpenAM, a certificate file must then be installed in the machines java keystore